# bash script is not running

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a Flask project running inside a kali vm, the webapp is running fine but I would like to run it at boot to be able to test it from another vm

created a `.sh` script

```
echo "Starting Flask server ... "

python3 app.py --host 0.0.0.0
```

The default port is 5000

I tried to use crontab
typed `crontab -e` 
and added the bash script to the crontab jobs

`@reboot /home/kali/Desktop/project/start.sh`

but when I do a nmap scan the port 5000 seems to be closed

what am i doing wrong

Comment: (1) Is the script executable? (2) Does the script work when you run it by hand? (3) Use a proper shebang. (4) `PATH` in cron is in general [different than your `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401621/108618). When in doubt, use full path to `python3` in the script. (5) `app.py` is a file, right? Do you know the working directory of cron and is the file there? Full path to `app.py` may be useful. (6) Instead of scanning ports (and possibly being stopped by the firewall) check if the process runs.

Comment: (7) Does cron mail anything to you? What? (8) Does cron log anything to syslog or to elsewhere? What?

Comment: I replaced `python3` with `/usr/bin/python3` as for cron emailing me I don't know how to do that yet, and `htop` does not seem to list the app process,  manually running `.sh.` file works fine